# edge to edge distance between patches with netlogo

Tags: netlogo

How can I compute edge to edge distance between patches with netlogo ? With the function "distance", distance between patches is calculated from center of patches.

Thank you very much for your help.
Have a good day
Marine

Answer (score 2):

If you want to measure the distance between the edges of your patches, you can create temporary turtles on the edges of your patches and measure the distance between these turtles. I assume that you want the shortest distance between any two points located on the edges of your two patches. In this case, you can create 8 turtles on each patch (the four corners and the four mid-edge points) and take the minimum distance between any pair of turtles.

```
to-report create-edge-turtles [ p ]
  let edge-turtles nobody
  ask p [
    foreach sort neighbors [
      sprout 1 [
        face ?
        fd distance ? / 2
        set edge-turtles (turtle-set edge-turtles self)
      ]
    ]
  ]
  report edge-turtles
end

to-report edge-distance [ patch-a patch-b ]
  let edges-a create-edge-turtles patch-a
  let edges-b create-edge-turtles patch-b
  let result min [ min [ distance myself ] of edges-b ] of edges-a
  ask edges-a [ die ]
  ask edges-b [ die ]
  report result
end
```

Comment: It took me a while to convince myself this is correct, but I now think it is.

Comment: why `sort neighbors`?

Comment: Hum... not sure anymore. Probably an artifact of a different approach I took at some point. Using `ask neighbors` and then `myself` instead of `?` to refer to each neighbor would be clearer and faster indeed.

Comment: Sorry I am beginner. I don't understand the line "min [ min [ distance myself ] of edges-b ] of edges-a". Is it possible that "min [ distance myself ] of edges-b ]" calculates the distance between a turtle of edges-a and all turtles of edges-b ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is what it does. I admit this line is a bit hard to read. For each `edges-a` turtle, it calculates the distance between this turtle and all the `edges-b` turtles. It takes the smallest of these distances and puts it into a list. Then it takes the smallest of all these smallest distances. In the end, this gives you the distance between the pair of A-B turtles that are the closest to one-another.

Comment: This code is really useful. It reports the value of the shortest distance between all patch edges. Is it possible to obtain the coordinates X and Y of two patch edges having the shortest distance ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It would be possible, yes. You'd have to find out _which_ of the temporary turtles are closest to one another (presumably using [`with-min`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#with-min)) instead of just finding the smallest distance. And then you'd report the coordinates of these turtles.