# Find the nearest polygon patches from edge to edge distance calculated between two polygons

Tags: netlogo

My objective is to find the nearest polygon patches from edge to edge distance calculated between two polygons. From [edge to edge distance between patches with netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935142/edge-to-edge-distance-between-patches-with-netlogo), here is my code to find the nearest polygon edges:

```
to-report calculate-distance [ID-polygon-A ID-polygon-B] 

let polygon-distance nobody
let edges-of-polygon-A create-edge-turtles ID-polygon-A 
let edges-of-polygon-B create-edge-turtles ID-polygon-B 
set polygon-distance min [ min [ distance myself ] of edges-of-polygon-B ] of edges-of-polygon-A 

## find the nearest edge in the polygon A
let nearest-edge-in-polygon-A edges-of-polygon-A with-min [ min [ distance myself ] of edges-of-polygon-B] 
ask nearest-edge-in-polygon-A [ 
  set color red
  set shape "x"
  set size 2 ]

## find the nearest edge in the polygon B
let nearest-edge-in-polygon-B edges-of-polygon-B with-min [ min [ distance myself ] of edges-of-polygon-A] 
ask nearest-edge-in-polygon-B [ 
  set color red
  set shape "x"
  set size 2 ]

ask edges-of-polygon-A with [ shape = "dot"] [ die ] 
ask edges-of-polygon-B with [ shape = "dot"] [ die ] 

report polygon-distance 
end
```

From [How to find a patch with a specific ID where there is a red turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976538/how-to-find-a-patch-with-a-specific-id-where-there-is-a-red-turtle), here is my code to find the nearest patches from the nearest edges:

```
show patches with [ ID-polygon = [ my-ID-polygon ] of myself and any? (turtles-here with [ color = red and shape = "x" ])
```

I don't understand why I obtain :

```
(agentset, 1 patch)
(agentset, 0 patches)
```

However, the two turtles with shape = "x" are well-visible on the polygons. If my code is not correct, is there another way to find the two nearest polygon patches based on distance ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A possible solution is "separating axis theorem" described here: http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html#section2